# Converting equation for Fixed Point Approximation Method

Tags: numerical-methods, fixed-point-theorems, newton-raphson, fixed-points

How can I convert this equation $y(t) = (Cvy + 32C^2)(1 − e^{-t/C}) − 32Ct$ into $t = g(t) $ to apply fixed point approximation method on it. I used $ t = (Cvy + 32C^2)(1 − e^{-t/C}) /32C$ but its giving me a root at around $0$ whereas I need root at around $8.7$. Can anybody please help me out?

Comment: You should note that, well, it's not just "around" $0$, $0$ *is* a root of $y$ (you can take your expressions with $t = 0$), so it's most likely not the fault of whichever method you're using but maybe the initial condition not being close enough to your non-zero root.

Comment: You want to find a solution to $y(t)=0$? Is it $C·v_y$ or $C_{vy}$?

Comment: @LutzLehmann its C * vy. Yes I want to find solution to y(t) = 0 using fixed point method

Comment: @BrunoB the only initial condition we can set is the choice of initial guess we use, as per my opinion. No matter what initial guess we take, the method always converges near 0. Is there any other condition that I can take initially that will allow me to get non-zero root?

Comment: Probably a repelling fixed point then, so that $g$ won't work I'm assuming. Maybe try a Newton method? Or a $g(t) := t - \alpha y(t)$ with a well-chosen $\alpha \neq 0$ such that your root becomes an attracting fixed point.